# How do eCommerce websites detect if a user is logged in?

Tags: javascript, css, volusion

I'm really not sure if this is the appropriate place to ask this question, so I apologize beforehand if it's not.

I'm working within the eCommerce platform Volusion, and they are quite restrictive with how much you can customize the site. One feature I would like, which they claim they do not currently support, is to have certain things display (or simply be different) if a user is logged in. One of the most basic uses for this would be to have a "Sign in" button on the homepage appear if they are not signed in, and have that button change to "Sign out" when they are.

I'm not sure how much specific information I can provide about my particular situation, other than I'm using Volusion, but I was wondering if maybe there is a common way that eCommerce sites in general detect when a user is logged in. I haven't been coding for very long, but I was thinking if I could just find some variable that the site uses for a signed in account, I could do something like

```
    if (USER IS LOGGED IN) {
   css blah blah
}
```

Hopefully someone is able to help me out with this.

Comment: It depends on what platform the website is being run. The only thing I really have experience with is Django (which is written in Python). It's very easy to get started with. In Django, you can simply look at the information in the `request`. So to check if a user is logged in you call `if request.user.is_authenticated():` . Unfortunately, I can't tell you anything about any other platform. Any idea what Volusion is written in?

Comment: A user's *authenticated* status is typically detected from the server side (PHP, etc.) and the content served to the user is modified accordingly.

Comment: If Volusion is doing your hosting, ASP. Do some reading about sessions and cookies. IIRC, you can only modify their HTML templates and CSS.

Answer (score 0):

The method we used to use was to detect for the existence of our session cookie. Of course, once the browser is closed all session-only TTL cookies are destroyed.